# Skylink - WebRTC - library not found for -lSocketRocket

Tags: ios, webrtc

I installed pod "SKYLINK" in my existing project and try to debug in iOS Device, got the following error

d: library not found for -lSocketRocket
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How to fix this error

Note:
   This issue is not shown in the new project or SKylink-iOS-Samples project https://github.com/Temasys/SkylinkSDK-iOS-Sample.

Answer (score 0):

This error due to SocketRocket Library, when you downloaded the code form git hub link which you had shared, and after you install pods, so during pod installation SocketRocket Library gets automatically installed.

But When we manually add skylink ios sdk, we do not add SocketRocket Library, that's why you are facing this issue.

So the solution for this is if you are manually adding skylink ios sdk then you had to add SocketRocket Library and other required libraries too.